# How to upgrade/install a package without pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I have pip2 and pip3 in my environment.

- pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
- pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python 3.4)
- Python 2.7.6
- Python 3.4.3

This is what I'm getting when I try to install (trying to install geopy: `pip2 install geopy`) or upgrade any package with pip2:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 562, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1017, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 864, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 826, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 145, in connect
    match_hostname(self.sock.getpeercert(),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in getpeercert
    for value in get_subj_alt_name(x509)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 94, in get_subj_alt_name
    asn1Spec=general_names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 825, in __call__
    stGetValueDecoder, self, substrateFun
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 391, in valueDecoder
    r.verifySizeSpec()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 252, in verifySizeSpec
    def verifySizeSpec(self): self._sizeSpec(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/constraint.py", line 32, in __call__
    '%s failed at: \"%s\"' % (self, sys.exc_info()[1])
ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64) failed at: "SubjectAltName().setComponents(GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(Na
medType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), ta
gSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=
0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(
componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet[...]
```

Full log [here](https://gist.github.com/anuras/7d7f9570e8ff0688bd278025a635b874) (sorry for the gist).

I can't upgrade pip2 (getting the same error as above). I also can't uninstall pip2, as pip2 uninstall pip returns

> Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS

Installing a package from source (`python setup.py install`) doesn't work either:

> error in geopy setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers.

I assume it's because version of setuptools is not being met (and I can't upgrade it via pip, as above). Please suggest me a way out of this mess.

Comment: The command you are executing is `pip2 install geopy`? If not please specify the exact command you are using.

Comment: Yes, `pip2 install geopy`, edited.

Comment: Is that the *only* output you got? That command does not print anything else? The error seems to imply that the python asn module is failing to verify a certificate because the `SubjectAlName` is too long, but I'm not sure. Tracebacks are awesome when you can look at the code to see what happened. Not so much for debugging installation problems.

Comment: Added log, sorry for the gist, I had no better idea where to put it.

Comment: Unfortunately, both `pip` and `python2` versions are too old (are you still running Ubuntu 14.04? It has reached EOL two years ago). Even if you manage to circumvent the `pip` error by e.g. downloading the newer wheel and installing it locally, e.g. via `pip2 install --user path/to/pip-18.1-py2-any.whl` and prepending `$HOME/.local/bin` to `PATH`, you will still be unable to install anything from PyPI until you update `python2` to at least 2.7.7 because of [this](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/issues/26). Python 2.7.6 is built against OpenSSL 0.9.8, which doesn't support TLSv1.2.

Comment: The `setup.py install` method will not work because you seem to have an ancient version of `setuptools` that doesn't support environment markers in the requirements.

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense, my ubuntu is long overdue for an update. Is there an easy way to manage python2 and 3 on the same machine that doesn't make it a pain in the butt? I'm not an advanced python user and having both of them has been a headache ever since.

Comment: You can try downloading the wheels of `setuptools` and `pip` and installing them for your user only: `pip2 install --user path/to/file.whl`. Then download `geopy` and `geographiclib` with a more recent `pip3`: `pip3 download "geographiclib>=1.49,<2"` and `pip3 download geopy --python-version 2 --only-binary=:all: --no-deps`. Now you can try installing with the local `pip2`: `$HOME/.local/bin/pip2 install --user path/to/geographiclib-1.49.tar.gz` and then `$HOME/.local/bin/pip2 install --user path/to/geopy-1.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`.

Comment: However, 1. no guarantee for success 2. your system gets even more cluttered and 3. it doesn't solve the main issue; the wise move still would be updating to at least 16.04.

Comment: Thanks, it did the job! Now I can carelessly avoid the updates until everything blows up in my face.

Comment: You like living on the edge :-) Nevertheless, glad I could help!

Comment: At my company we have some systems still running python2.6 (due to a big client not wanting to upgrade...). In order to make things work we create a new virtual env from [this](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/changes/) (up to 15.2.0 it still supports python2.6), we are careful to specify `--no-setuptools --no-pip --no-wheel` and we install `setuptools`, `pip` and `wheel` manually specifying the latest version that supports python2.6. Seems like if you want to keep using that outdated python 2.7 you will have to do something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Try download `geopy` package from https://pypi.org/project/geopy/
and run

```
python setup.py install
```